# Error when i configure spring boot app as eureka server and client at same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am developing a spring boot app and I want it to be an eureka server and an eureka client at same time, to achieve that I modified `application.properties` file :

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

these properties allow the app to register as eureka client to the eureka server( which is the same app ).
It works fine, but when I shutdown the application I get this error

```
2021-09-04 15:55:25.421  INFO 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-09-04 15:55:25.437  INFO 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-09-04 15:55:25.445  INFO 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2021-09-04 15:55:28.447  INFO 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
2021-09-04 15:55:32.580  INFO 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/} exception=java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect stacktrace=com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.delete(WebResource.java:591)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.cancel(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:91)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister(DiscoveryClient.java:972)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown(DiscoveryClient.java:948)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.run(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.destroy(GenericScope.java:390)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.destroy(GenericScope.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1152)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1026)
    at org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin.shutdown(SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.java:160)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:260)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
    ... 83 more

2021-09-04 15:55:32.581  WARN 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2021-09-04 15:55:36.710  INFO 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect stacktrace=com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.delete(WebResource.java:591)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.cancel(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister(DiscoveryClient.java:972)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown(DiscoveryClient.java:948)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.run(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.destroy(GenericScope.java:390)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.destroy(GenericScope.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1152)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1026)
    at org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin.shutdown(SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.java:160)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:260)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
    ... 84 more

2021-09-04 15:55:36.711  WARN 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2021-09-04 15:55:36.724 ERROR 8860 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/host.docker.internal:8761 - de-registration failedCannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister(DiscoveryClient.java:972) ~[eureka-client-
...
```

So how we can avoid first error mentioned in this post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be normal since Eureka monitors the instances so it can happen that it is not able to call them in certain situations.

Here, the service tries to unregister itself from Eureka as an Eureka Client but before that it closes its own HTTP listener as a webservice (does not accept more traffic).

So it can't call itself as an Eureka Client at unregister but this is not really a problem since it is shutting down as an Eureka Server.

Solution: Use a separate Eureka instance.

You can also ignore these log entries by: `logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=WARN` or `logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=ERROR` or etc.