# It is possible to make a spring boot app behave as a eureka server and client at the same time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I already developed a spring boot app and I want to add the two spring cloud dependencies (eureka client, eureka server) to make it behave as a eureka server and client at the same time. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want to mix between you app and discovery service functionality? your app and the discovery service have to be separated. Is it theoretical question or you have tried something and faced with some errors ?

Comment: Yes I have tried to do that because I have just two services, so I want one of them to act as a server and client at the same time, and actually I faced with some errors as I described in this question that I have asked before [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056779/error-when-i-configure-spring-boot-app-as-eureka-server-and-client-at-same-time).

Comment: Yes it's mine .

Answer (score 1):

If you create an Eureka instance with Spring Boot, it registers itself into itself so it acts as a client and a server but I would separate Eureka from other services.

Here's an example: https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/teahouse/tree/main/eureka
Basically it is:

1. Add `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`
2. Use `@EnableEurekaServer` on a `@Configuration` or on the `@SpringBootApplication` class
3. It's good to name it accordingly: `spring.application.name=eureka`

Comment: Hi Jonathan thanks for your answer, actually I have tried that and it works fine, the eureka server registers itself into itself as you said, but when I shutdown the app I faced with errors as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056779/error-when-i-configure-spring-boot-app-as-eureka-server-and-client-at-same-time).

Comment: Why are you opening duplicates?